# Translate struct from c to mips

Tags: c, mips

How can I translate this C code to Mips ?
I have a struct for List, List consists of an array, each index in array contains a character and an integer, how can I translate the list in Mips in .data and how can I access the priority and data of an array of type entry in main?.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 20

typedef struct{
   int priority;
   char data;
}entry;

typedef struct{
  entry arr[MAX];
  int Size;
}List;

int main()
{
   List l1;
   entry array[5];
   int priority=array[0].priority;
   char ch=array[0].data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `entry` a size and alignment, by giving each of its fields an offset and size and an alignment.  I'm going add an additional `char` field at the beginning so you can see better how this is done.

| field | type | size | align | pad | start | last | next | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `extra` | `char` | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | first field |
| `priority` | `int` | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 8 | second field: padding of 3 for `int` so that the **start** offset is rounded up to a multiple of **align**=4 (from **next**=1 as left by the preceding field) |
| `data` | `char` | 1 | 1 | 0 | 8 | 8 | 9 | third field |
| *final padding* |  | 0 | 4 | 3 | 9 | 11 | 12 | alignment=max of the preceding |
| **totals** | `entry` | 12 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 12 | summary of whole struct |

Each field has a type, and that type has a size and alignment requirement.  For the primitive types, the alignment requirement is usually the same as the size of the field, and, for structures, the alignment is the max of all its fields.

The first field gets offset 0 and does not require padding.

For each field after the first, sufficient padding is placed in front of the field's start offset so that its start offset is properly aligned for its data type.

There is also final padding, which we can (or not) think of as a hidden last field of zero length except for its padding.  This last field, and the whole structure, have an alignment requirement of the max of all the other fields' alignment requirements.

Now we know the size of `entry`, so we can add to the table (or do a separate table) for the next struct.  As the first field is an array of 20, we multiply its size by 20.

| field | type | size | align | pad | start | last | next | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `arr` | `entry` | 240=12*20 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 239 | 240 | first field |
| `size` | `int` | 4 | 4 | 0 | 240 | 243 | 244 | second field |
| *final padding* |  | 0 | 4 | 0 |  |  |  | none required |
| **totals** | `List` | 244 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 243 | 244 | summary of whole struct |

Ok, now we know that `List` has size 244 and an alignment requirement of 4.

If you're doing `List l1` as a global variable (recommended) then:

```
    .data
    ...
    .align 2  # asking for 2^2=4 byte alignment
l1: .space 244
    ...

    .text
    ...
    la $a0, l1         # $a0 = & l1;
    lw $t0, 36($a0)    # $t0 = l1.arr[3].priority
    ...
```

---

Your C code has `List l1` as a local variable (rather than as a global variable in the `.data` section).  The computations of size and alignment are the same for local variables, but this variable would live on the stack, which means you'd have to allocate stack space for it and compute its initial offset relative to the stack pointer.

```
    .text
    ...
main:
    addiu $sp, $sp, -244 # allocate space for List l1 as local variable
    ...
    addiu $a0, $sp, 0    # $a0 = & l1; List l1 is lives at sp+0 .. sp+243
    lw $t0, 36($a0)      # $t0 = l1.arr[3].priority
    ...
    addiu $sp, $sp, 244  # release stack space
    ...
```

The stack pointer can be assumed as at least 4 byte alignment, and possibly 8 byte on some systems (e.g. 64-bit).

Comment: Thanks alot, so for me after removing the extra field, the size of entry will be 11 and the space that I will need for list will be 220 right?

Comment: No, you forgot to also subtract the padding for the now first field.  11 wouldn't make sense in any case, since that is an odd number.  You want multiples of the max alignment requirement of all the fields.  Here, that's 4 so you want multiples of that.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused , it would be 8 for entry?

Comment: Yes.  Try to follow the rules logically.  Padding is needed to make things line up properly.  Too much padding can be as bad as too little.  We put final padding in so that when there's an array the 2nd array element (at index 1) will line up properly as well as the first element (at index 0).